# Order all record by result of divison of count of rows and count of rows with where condition

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Here's the table I am working with below.

[image]

What I am trying to do is to get the total count of rows for each emp_id as total_count, then get the total count of rows for each emp_id where tos >0 as total_eligible, and then order them by total_eligible/total_count.

[Here's the fiddle I am working with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a2d55/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select emp_id, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when tos > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as total_eligible,
       avg(case when tos > 0 then 1.0 else 0 end) as total_eligible_ratio
from table t
group by emp_id
order by total_eligible * 1.0 / total;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5f042/6) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Is there a way to also get(select) the value of the total_eligible * 1.0 / total?